# Chrome- Position Fixed Header hidden under scroll bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

My position fixed header is getting hidden under scroll bar of container of header. This is just happening in chrome only. FF and IE are fine. See Below.

[image]

I have tried changing z indexes, top & left properties of header.  My pop is ui modal of bootstrap.

Comment: which version of chrome? which platform?

Comment: Windows 7 , Chrome Version 51.0.2704.63 m

Comment: Can you please shear your code in jsfiddle or codepen ? So we can check

Comment: Strange, I am getting the opposite on a Mac, whereby the scrollbar is hidden underneath a fixed header.

Comment: I have a similar problem with fixed position element: http://jsfiddle.net/v1dgnw68/
Click "Default" to see the "dropdown" rendering behind the scrollbar - only in chrome.